# Rule of thumb for number of leafs and trees in a random forest?

Tags: random-forest, hyperparameter-tuning

I wonder if there is a rough estimate or rule of thumb or the like to guess the optimal number of leafs and trees in a random forest?

Or would you just use a hyperparameter search method?

[image: img]

Answer (score 1):

Hyperparameter search would be a useful method to find the number of leaves and trees for a Random Forest model.

The number of leaves and trees for a Random Forest model will vary widely based on the dataset.